# How should I get actual path of user gallery in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to access a user's gallery.
I tried using plugins like `image_picker`, but they provide a temporary path.
So even if I saved the path, the app couldn't load it the next time.
And I couldn't delete photos from the user's gallery.
I've been trying to find a solution for a couple of days, but couldn't find one.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider to use [Photo_Manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager#delete-entities) plugin.